# Difference between SequenceGenerator in class level and field level -Hibernate

Tags: oracle, hibernate

is there any difference in giving `@SequenceGenerator` annotaion in `class` level and `Field` level.

Class Level

```
@SequenceGenerator(name = "customerProfileSeq", sequenceName = "SEQ_CUSTOMER_PROFILE_KEY")
public class CustomerProfile {
```

Field Level

```
  @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "CustomerProfileSeq", sequenceName = "SEQ_CUSTOMER_PROFILE_KEY")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "customerProfileSeq")
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private long id;
```

In our application the `SequenceGenerator` specified in class level entities generating sequence with HILO algorithm. there is gap between numbers. The field level entities generate normal increment values. Is the reason because where we mention the `SequenceGenerator`?